# want to add template in mail code

Tags: php, email, templates

I've a script that send mail in plain text and i want to add mail template with table and td
that script is using this code for message:

```
       $body= nl2br('Dear Family and Friends,'.$space."\n\n".' This message is from
 '.$info[0]->first_name.' '.$info[0]->last_name.' who is challenging you to join him 
        at Grow for the Cure to raise money for lung cancer research. '.$space."\n\n".'Have
         you ever wondered what it would be like to see your buddy sport a slick mustache or
         rock some big ol pork chop sideburns? Your friend has courageously provided his face 
        as a blank canvas and put YOU in charge.'.$space."\n".'Grow for the Cure and the Bonnie
     J. Addario Lung Cancer Foundation invite you to click on the link below to see how your
         friend has volunteered to raise money for lung cancer research. Check out his personal
     page where you will be able to see which look is in the lead, and make a donation to your
     favorite choice!'.$space."\n\n".'Your friend needs your support and the research community
     definitely needs your help. Lung cancer kills more people than breast, prostate, colon, 
    liver, kidney, and melanoma cancers combined. Yet, it receives a fraction of 
        the attention and funding. With your help, we are going to change that focus and make
     an impact.'.$space."\n"."All donations go to the Bonnie J. Addario Lung Cancer 
        Foundation and will be used on the front lines of lung cancer research. 
        Your donation WILL make a difference.<p style='color:blue;font-weight:bold;'>"
.$data['glink'].'</p>'.$space."\nHere's what your friend has to say:\n\n".'
     '.$comments."\n\n"."Please visit xyz.org today!\n\nGw  is an affiliate of the\n"."Bonnie\n\n");
```

How can I implement our html code in this?
Please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Don't use a table in an email. Please.

Comment: this mail content is in home.php I'm not going to use in any mail client.

Comment: Hmmm.  Is your question how to use html tags inside the message?

Comment: yes, in php file i've posted code here that is using for message.

Comment: Sending an HTML mail in PHP is tricky if you're building it up yourself. Use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer, which it far easier to send a MIME message.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, you can simply do this:

```
$body= nl2br('Dear <b>Family</b> and <p style="color:red;">Friends</p>
,'.$space."\n\n".'This message is from '.$info[0]->first_name.' and 
more text here');
```

Just be sure to backslash any embedded double or single quotes like

```
echo "He said \"That's lame!\" or something.";
echo 'He said "That\'s lame!" or something.';
```

Comment: @Amit, you could check the "correct answer" checkmark if this answers your questions. That's how we do around here. :)

Comment: i want use this types html code there (i've deleted some part case that was to long and can't post here): <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="600" height="345">
      <td height="522" width="567"><b>Dear<br>This message...
    </td>
  </tr>
  
</table>

Comment: Well, what's the problem? Just do it!